# Query returns empty cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So I was trying to display the content in the database but apparently the cursor equals null. Are there any issues with my query?

My database has three columns (ID, name, date). Name and date should be displayed on the Activity.
I provided you the code of the ContentProvider and my contract. If you see any errors please let me know.

**ContentProvider**

```
public class EventProvider extends ContentProvider {


private static final int EVENTS = 100;
private static final int EVENT_ID = 101;

private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

static {
    sUriMatcher.addURI(EventContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, EventContract.PATH_EVENTS, EVENTS);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(EventContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, EventContract.PATH_EVENTS + "/#", EVENT_ID);
}

public static final String LOG_TAG = EventProvider.class.getSimpleName();

private EventDbHelper mDbHelper = new EventDbHelper(getContext());

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mDbHelper = new EventDbHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection,  String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    // This cursor will hold the result of the query
    Cursor cursor;

    // Figure out if the URI matcher can match the URI to a specific code
    int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match) {
        case EVENTS:

            cursor = database.query(EventEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        case EVENT_ID:

            selection = EventEntry._ID + "=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};

            cursor = database.query(EventEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot query unknown URI " + uri);
    }
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}
```

**Contract**

```
public final class EventContract {

private EventContract (){}

public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.example.deadline";
public static final String PATH_EVENTS = "events";
public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("context://" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY);

public static final class EventEntry implements BaseColumns{

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_CONTENT_URI, PATH_EVENTS);
    public static final String CONTENT_LIST_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY
            + "/" + PATH_EVENTS;
    public final static String TABLE_NAME = "events";

    public final static String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public final static String COLUMN_EVENT_NAME = "name";
    public final static String COLUMN_EVENT_DATE = "date";

    public final static String TABLE_SORT_BY = "name ASC";
}
```

}

Comment: An empty `Cursor` and null are different things. That said, you've not shown your `insert()` method in your `ContentProvider`. How are you putting things in your database? Are you sure there's anything in there to return?

Comment: I viewed the data manually. So there definetely is data in the database.